# Set maximum number of item in Select List - html

Tags: javascript, html

How can i set the maximum number of items to be allowed inside a list box ?

That is if i set the maxsize to 4 and the select list has 4 items then no more value can be inserted !

how to do that ?

[there will be 2 lists, user will be able to move options one to another, but one of them will have the limit]

Comment: I you can write code to move one item to another, it should not be that hard to check the number of items too. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML doesn't offer facilities for this. You've just to add an extra `if` check in your JS code which moves items from one to other list.

E.g.

```
if (list.options.length < list.size) {
    // Add item.
} else {
    // Show a warning/error?
}
```

Comment: thnx man, it will do the work, i though HTML got some inbuilt things like `text`

Comment: The `maxlength`, you mean? That's ignored/circumventable by JS as well. A `input.value='new value which is longer than maxlength';` will just set the entire value.

Comment: but is it possible to run JS on my code ? [like can you run JS on this SO to change any text's value ?]

Comment: Yes, JS is fully controllable by the client (it can even be disabled altogether). You should always do constraint validation in the server side as well (and ensure that your JS code is unobtrusive).

Comment: can you tell me how to code JS to auto fill the comment with a Signature ?

Comment: That goes offtopic. Press `Ask Question` button on right top.

Comment: @BalusC  you broke my heart :(

Comment: hey man read it -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243441/script-to-change-value-of-a-text-javascript