# Script to change value of a text - Javascript

Tags: javascript

From this question i came to know text element's value can be changed by JS [Set maximum number of item in Select List - html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243303/set-maximum-number-of-item-in-select-list-html)

can anyone give some code or some tips ?

*My intention is not hacking, i need to know this, coz i'm writing a web app where most of the validation is done by JS*

`Edit`
Looking for guide on running JS from client side on a page served by a server [on some text where it's **readonly="true"** ] !

Comment: *where most of the validation is done by JS*. If it's critical validation, you should *also* do the validations @ the server, really.

Comment: Yup, with out a doubt you are right ! but it's no offense learning the JS hack :)

Answer (score 32):

For example, if you have a html text element like this:

```
<p id="textelement">I am a text element</p>
```

You can change the text inside with JS like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("textelement").innerHTML = "New text inside the text element!";
</script>
```

You can use this technique with any HTML element which can contain text, such as options in a select list (`<option>` tag). You can select elements in other ways:

- **getElementById()** Accesses the first element with the specified id
- **getElementsByName()**  Accesses all elements with a specified name
- **getElementsByTagName()**   Accesses all elements with a specified tagname

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp).

PS - If you want to change the *value* of an element's attribute, and not its inner text, you should use the setAttribute() method; for example, if you have:

```
...
<option id="optionone" value="red">Nice color</option>
...
```

and want to change the *value* attribute, you should do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("optionone").setAttribute("value", "green");
</script>
```

More about this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/met_element_setattribute.asp).

Comment: i know that man, but how do you execute JS from client side on a page served by server ?

Comment: You want to execute Javascript on the server-side? While that is possible, you are better off using PHP, Ruby, Java or some other language focused on the server-side. Javascript focus is on the client-side, i.e., it runs on your browser.

Comment: You got me wrong man, i'm looking for something like a SCRIPT WHICH CAN ADD A SIGNATURE TO COMMENT IN SO

Comment: I'm sorry, you have to be more specific. Javascript runs in your browser, if you want to make permanent changes to a document served by a server, there must also exist a server-side script to accept and perform those changes; those changes can at best be requested by javascript on the client side (using a technique called Ajax), but must be performed by a server-side script.

Comment: can you write and run a JS which can change/set a text in the search field of StackOverflow's page ? _search field is in the top right corner_

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">var searchInputArray = document.getElementsByName('q'); searchInput = searchInputArray[0]; searchInput.setAttribute("value", "some text in want to put in search");</script>

Comment: This code only has direct effect on the client-side of things, in other words, in only works in the document that is currently loaded in your browser. But of course, if you submit the search (by pressing Enter), the value that you changed with JS is the value that will be submitted to the server for searching.